# Issue with Drop down menu for auto suggest search bar

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, searchbar

I am trying to make a searchbar with auto suggest.The search bar is a text input box. every time something is entered in the text box i am making a Ajax call to php page which will return a unordered list ( the php page will echo html for a unordered list with class name result with li as search result). I have a div (which id="demo") below the text box into which i am putting the unordered list. Initially div demo has display: none; but the text box is focused it becomes display:block; and when the text box is focused out it becomes display:none;. I am doing this because i want the dropdown menu to disappear when the textbox is not focused. But i have problem here, if i click on a li in the unordered list then the value of the text box must be equal to the content in the li. I have tried various ways to do so. I have given a onlineclick attribute to all the li element under the ul.result. The onlclick attribute calls a functions which makes the value of the text box equal to the text content of the li. But it is not working, the div is disappearing but the function is not being called.
This the index.php page.

```
 <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="autosuggest.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <input name="search" class="search" type="text"                                  onkeyup="autosuggest(this.value,event.which)"  autocomplete="off" />
 <div id="demo" style="display: none;"></div>
 </body>
```

this the code in js file. i have given onclick function here as alert();
just to test the functioning but it is not working. can anyone please help me with it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".search").focusin(function(){
    $("#demo").css("display","block");
});
$(".search").focusout(function(){

    $("#demo").css("display","none");
});
$("#demo").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
});
});
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul").delegate("li", "click", function(e){
     //e.currentTarget(); This will give the current selected object 
     //put an alert this will give you the selected list item 
});
```

Whenever you use list items you have distinctly identify the list item that has been selected and for that you need to use delegate function.